# Why does my ACL need to be configured this way to grant access that I want?

Tags: firewall, acl

I have a secondary network from my ER605 router, this is used that the connected device, a raspberry pi, can be isolated. I use it to quarantine and scan incoming files from dubious sources (such as my in-laws perpetually malware afflicted computers). I need to be able to access the pi and exfiltrate scanned files to my primary network. I plan on using VNC for access and putting ok'd files directly on my QNAP NAS via SMB share.

ACL rule 5 blocks communication from the quarantine network to my primary network. In order to get VNC to my quarantine pi from my primary network I initially added rule 4, which was insufficient (online reading suggested I needed an ACL for return messages), so I added a version of rule 3 that referenced the VNC service, and that still failed. On a whim I tried creating the VNC_duplex service definition which swaps source and destiation port and changing rule #3 from VNC service to VNC duplex, and viola VNC worked!

I'm pretty happy this is working, but I'm not certain why, or if it's secure. Am I correct in understanding that ACL rule 3 allows for a malicious script to send a message from any port on the raspberry pi to port 5900 on any device on my primary network? What's the semantic way of understanding this, and could it be made more secure?

My network and VLANS:

[image]

[image]

I have set up some ip ranges as well to describe areas of my network that I want to segment/grant access to:

[image]

[image]

My service types (the last four are custom entered by me):

[image]

And finally my ACL:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> online reading suggested I needed an ACL for return messages), so I added a version of rule 3 that referenced the VNC service, and that still failed. On a whim I tried creating the VNC_duplex service definition which swaps source and destiation port and changing rule #3 from VNC service to VNC duplex, and viola VNC worked!

When the Pi sends replies to your computer, *the Pi is the source.*

It is not only that the 'return' packets have the Pi's IP address as the "source IP" – they also have the corresponding port number *on the Pi side* as the "source port".

```
Connection:        192.168.0.PC:54321 <--> 192.168.2.10:5900

Packets from PC:   src = 192.168.0.PC:54321, dst = 192.168.2.10:5900
Packets from Pi:   src = 192.168.2.10:5900, dst = 192.168.0.PC:54321
```

All of the original service templates in your firewall are defined for the "forward" direction only; e.g. the "VNC" template matches 5900 as the destination port – which, as explained, only matches packets that have the VNC server as their destination but not the 'return' packets.

> Am I correct in understanding that ACL rule 3 allows for a malicious script to send a message from any port on the raspberry pi to port 5900 on any device on my primary network?

No. What it allows is the opposite – it allows for a script to send a message **from port 5900** on the raspberry pi **to any port** on your primary network. (The 'Source' in "Source Port = 5900" *really means* the source of the packets.)

Since the source port of a connection *can* be chosen arbitrarily (if wanted), this means the primary network is wide open to anyone who *knows* about the existence of this exception; all they need to do is ask the OS to bind a connection to local port 5900. (But on the other hand, since the source port is usually randomized and the range starts well beyond 5900, anyone who *doesn't* know about this exception is unlikely to discover it by accident.)

> What's the semantic way of understanding this,

"Source" really means the source of the individual **packet**, not of the whole connection. (Actually, the port could almost be considered part of the packet's "transport-layer" address, and indeed in several other non-IP protocols it was literally part of the address.)

Each port is associated with a specific endpoint, in the same way that each IP address is associated with a specific endpoint – if you make a connection to the Pi, you don't expect that a 'return' packet from the Pi would still show the Pi's IP address as a "destination", and the same applies to the port numbers.

> and could it be made more secure?

The usual approach is to avoid such reflexive ACLs entirely and to use a **stateful** firewall. Most routers are capable of keeping track of active connections ("states" or "flows") – they kind of *have to* do this if they implement typical 1:many NAT – and the firewall filter may have a special rule that allows any packet corresponding to an "established" connection (as in iptables/nftables), or allow such packets implicitly (as in pf).

It seems the ER603 gained support for stateful ACLs [in firmware 2.1](https://www.reddit.com/r/TPLink_Omada/comments/10ayz4c/er605_v21_release_with_mdns_and_stateful_acl/). (People seem to be saying it doesn't work, though.)

If you *must* use stateless ACLs, then the alternate approach is to only allow 'return' packets that have the **TCP "ACK" flag** set. The initial packet of a TCP connection *never* has this flag set, while all other packets do; it's enough to have a single rule that allows TCP ACK packets on any port.

Naturally, this approach only works for TCP – you can't do much about UDP without state tracking, except hope that nobody discovers the hole that your reflexive ACL makes.

You should also have another rule that allows ICMP 'return' packets as well (e.g. Echo Reply and the various ICMP 'error' messages – *at minimum* "Fragmentation Needed" needs to be allowed, but preferably other errors such as "Unreachable" should be allowed as well).

Comment: Excellent answer, impeccable clarifying detail!